# Concatenar dos condiciones en bash

Tags: bash, condiciones

me gustaria pasarle dos condiciones a un if y que si una de las dos se cumple entre dentro del if. He probado con esto y no me funciona

```
elif [[ $1 == "-h" ]] || [[$1 == "--help" ]]; then
```

Comment: ¿No te falta un espacio delante del segundo $1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esa línea a mi me funciona si la pones así:

```sh
elif [[ $1 == "-h" ]] || [[ $1 == "--help" ]]; then
```

Fíjate en el espacio entre los corchetes `[[` y el parámetro `$1` de diferencia entre lo que tu has puesto y la sintaxis correcta. Tanto el operador de test `[` como el operador de test extendido `[[` necesitan espacio tanto al principio como al final de sus contenidos. [Aquí encontrarás más información](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html).

Aparte de eso, según parece intentas pasarle parametros a tu script en bash.

Mi recomendación es usar CASE de este modo:

```sh
case "$1" in

    "-h" | "--help")
        ## aqui pones lo que quieres hacer en bash si se cumple la condición
    ;;

    *)
        ## aqui pones lo que sea que hace sin parametro ninguno o bien sin parametro encontrado antes
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me había dado cuenta.